# Not able to establish connection to the kerberos and SASL enabled kafka producer

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, apache-kafka, kerberos, spring-kafka

I am trying to connect to kafka producer that is kerberos and SSL enabled,
Here is the properties.yml

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude[0]: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
    exclude[1]: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
  kafka:
    topics:
      - name: SOME_TOPIC
        num-partitions: 5
        replication-factor: 1
    bootstrap-servers:
      - xxx:9092
      - yyy:9092
      - zzz:9092
    autoCreateTopics: false
    template:
      default-topic: SOME_TOPIC
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
    properties:
      security:
        protocol: SASL_SSL
      ssl:
        enabled:
          protocols: TLSv1.2
        truststore:
          location: C:\\resources\\truststorecred.jks
          password: truststorepass
          type: JKS
      sasl:
        mechanism: GSSAPI
        kerberos:
          service:
            name: kafka
```

and VM options as follow.

-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\jaas.conf 
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=C:\resources\krb5.ini

Jaas.conf as follow

```
KafkaClient {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  storeKey=true
  keyTab="C:\\resources\\serviceacc@xxx.keytab"
  principal="serviceacc@xxx.COM"
  useTicketCache=true
  serviceName="kafka";
};
```

able to logged in to kerberos but immediate it is failing with below exception.

```
    bootstrap.servers = [xxxx.com:9092, yyyy.com:9092, zzzz.com:9092]
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 120000
    retries = 5
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = kafka
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = C:\\resources\\truststorecred.jks
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS

2019-12-21 14:56:16.115  INFO 24216 --- [           main] o.a.k.c.s.authenticator.AbstractLogin    : Successfully logged in.
2019-12-21 14:56:16.117  INFO 24216 --- [xxx.COM] o.a.k.c.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin  : [Principal=serviceacc@xxx.COM]: TGT refresh thread started.
2019-12-21 14:56:16.118  INFO 24216 --- [xxx.COM] o.a.k.c.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin  : [Principal=serviceacc@xxx.COM]: TGT valid starting at: Sat Dec 21 14:56:15 IST 2019
2019-12-21 14:56:16.119  INFO 24216 --- [xxx.COM] o.a.k.c.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin  : [Principal=serviceacc@xxx.COM]: TGT expires: Sun Dec 22 00:56:15 IST 2019
2019-12-21 14:56:16.119  INFO 24216 --- [xxx.COM] o.a.k.c.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin  : [Principal=serviceacc@xxx.COM]: TGT refresh sleeping until: Sat Dec 21 23:13:36 IST 2019
2019-12-21 14:56:16.912  INFO 24216 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 1.0.2
2019-12-21 14:56:16.912  INFO 24216 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : 2a121f7b1d402825
2019-12-21 14:56:22.085  WARN 24216 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.common.network.SslTransportLayer   : Failed to send SSL Close message 

java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.flush(SslTransportLayer.java:213) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.close(SslTransportLayer.java:176) ~[kafka-clients-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeAll(Utils.java:703) [kafka-clients-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.close(KafkaChannel.java:61) [kafka-clients-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.doClose(Selector.java:741) [kafka-clients-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.close(Selector.java:729) [kafka-clients-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:522) [kafka-clients-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:412) [kafka-clients-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:460) [kafka-clients-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1006) [kafka-clients-1.0.2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]

2019-12-21 14:56:22.087  WARN 24216 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -2 terminated during authentication. This may indicate that authentication failed due to invalid credentials.
2019-12-21 14:56:26.598  WARN 24216 --- [| adminclient-1] o.a.k.common.network.SslTransportLayer   : Failed to send SSL Close message
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change worked for me

```
security.protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
```